# Age of location returned from LocationServices

Tags: android, location-services

I need to ensure the location I use is fresh:

Is there a way of finding out how old the location result returned by `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` is?

If not: if I register a location listener to the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` (with `setNumUpdates(1)` and `setMaxWaitTime(0)`) then will it update if the location has not changed from the one returned by `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a very easy way. You can get the time of a Location fix by calling `getTime()` like this:

```
Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);
long locationAge = System.currentTimeMillis() - currentLocation.getTime();

if (locationAge <= 60 * 1000) { // not older than 60 seconds
    // do something with the location
}
```

The documentation recommends not to use System.currentTimeMillis() for time comparisons, but I never experienced any flaws with this method. However, you should consider reading the (short) documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Illiminat's answer, as of API 17 the `getElapsedRealtimeNanos()` method has been added. From the documentation of the method...

> Return the time of this fix, in elapsed real-time since system boot.
>
> This value can be reliably compared to SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos(), to calculate the age of a fix and to compare Location fixes. This is reliable because elapsed real-time is guaranteed monotonic for each system boot and continues to increment even when the system is in deep sleep (unlike getTime().

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getElapsedRealtimeNanos()

Therefore the following should now be the most precise way of doing calculating this

```
Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);
long locationAge = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - currentLocation.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
long ageLimitNanoSec = 60_000_000_000; // 60 seconds in nano seconds
if (locationAge <= ageLimitNanoSec) { 
    // do something with the location
}
```